# Django rest framework serialize filtered Foreign keys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

#### Models.py

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    views = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()


class ModelB(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modelB', blank=True, null=True)
    string = models.CharField()
```

#### Views.py

```
class ModelAListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ModelASerialezer
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all().prefetch_related('modelb')

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset.filter(modelb__string__icontains=request.GET['string']), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

#### Serializers.py

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    modelB = ModelBSerializer(source='modelB', many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        exclude = ('views',)

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = '__all__'
```

If I need to search by "string" field I can write

```
modelA.objects.filter(modelB__string__icontains=request.GET['string']).values('modelB__string')
```

Which return ModelB instances **only with necessary `string` values**:

```
<QuerySet [{'modelB__string': 'Test1'}]>
```

When I filter by modelb_string I expect to get only filtered FK value:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "views": 0,
    "modelb": [
        {
            "id": 46,
            "string": "Test1",
            "item": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**but** I get all FK values:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "views": 0,
    "modelb": [
        {
            "id": 46,
            "string": "Test1",
            "item": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 47,
            "string": "Test85",
            "item": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 48,
            "string": "Test64",
            "item": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post your serializer code

Comment: @MarcellErasmus, update. But it's just very basic serializer. Or are you asking for the ModelA serializer?

Comment: Your serializer is telling DRF to serializer `__all__` fields and that's why you're seeing what you're seeing. You need to pass only the fields you want to see in the serializer

Comment: Update question with all code tried to get the desired outcome please. I'm trying to understand your process. I cant see where you tried to filter.

Comment: @HigorRossato, I need to get only filtred FK. I update the question with an example.

Comment: Can you please update your question with view code as well ? How's that queryset being serialized and returned as response ?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be on your view class

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


modelA.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch(modelB, queryset=modelB.objects.filter(string__icontains=request.GET['string'])))
```

This returns modelA objects with filtered modelB FK related instances

Answer (score 0):

Few points worth mentioning :

1. You don't need to implement the `list` function and redo what's already being done in the [mixin](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0407a0df8a16fdac94bbd08d49143a74a88001cd/rest_framework/mixins.py#L37)
2. If we want to customise the queryset then we should override the `get_queryset`, [details](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters)

Something like this :

```
class ModelAListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ModelASerialezer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = modelA.objects.all()

        given_string = self.request.query_params.get('string', None)

        if given_string is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(modelB__string__icontains=given_string)

        return queryset
```

3. Maybe you should consider renaming the field `string`

References :

- https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0407a0df8a16fdac94bbd08d49143a74a88001cd/rest_framework/mixins.py#L37
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't solve FK values problem. I steel get all FK instances.

Comment: Can you log your string and check what's the value of that ? Also try logging queryset before & after filtering.

Comment: return queryset is right, but JSON same as was. Log before filter:
`<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'modelb__string': 'Test1221'}, {'id': 1, 'modelb__string': 'Тест1221'}, {'id': 2, 'modelb__string': 'Тест85'}, {'id': 4, 'modelb__string': None}]>`
Log after filter: `<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'modelb__string': 'Test1221'}]>`